# Proving the arithmetic mean equals the geometric mean when $a=b$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Arithmetic mean $a,b \in \mathbb R$ is $A(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}$

Geomtric mean $a,b \in\left[0,\infty\right]$  is $G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab}$

I'm trying to prove that $G(a,b)=A(a,b)$ if and only if $a=b$.

First I went in the easy direction of if $a=b$ then $G(a,b)=A(a,b)$. Assume $a=b$, then substitute $a$ in for $b$ in the arithmetic/geometric, and after some simply arithmetic  $b=b$ and we're done.

The second direction I tried using a similar approach and am having a bit of trouble.
Assume $G(a,b)=A(a,b)$
$$\frac{a+b}{2}=\sqrt{ab}$$
$$a+b=2\sqrt{ab}$$
$$a^2+2ab+b^2=4ab$$
$$a^2+b^2=2ab$$

From here I cannot see how to show $a=b$. Is there an algebraic trick I am missing? Or, is this approach inappropriate for this direction? Hints welcome!

Comment: You're almost there. Subtract $2ab$ from both sides. Then $a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = 0$, i.e. $(a-b)^2 = 0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: I feel so silly for missing that! Thanks!

Comment: In the other hand, the series stops to exist if a becomes equal to b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2=0\implies a-b=0\implies a=b$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ G(a,b) = \sqrt{a\cdot b}\quad\forall a\cdot b \in [0,\infty),\\
\text{ and  } A(a,b) = \frac{a + b}{2} \quad\forall a,b \in \mathbb R$$

Now, we are given that $a = b$, and we need to prove that $G(a,b) = A(a,b)$

$$a = b \\
\implies a - b = 0 \\
\implies (a-b)^2 = 0 \\
\implies a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = 0\\
\implies a^2 + b^2 = 2ab\\
\implies a^2 + b^2 + 2ab = 2ab + 2ab\\
\implies (a+b)^2 = 4ab\\
\implies a + b = 2\sqrt{ab}\\
\implies \frac{a+b}{2} = \sqrt{ab}\\
\implies A(a,b) = G(a,b)$$

Q.E.D.

Note, this equality will not hold if either $a$ or $b$ is negative when the other is positive.